# Extending TestCompile and TestRuntime inside a plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy

With a "normal" `JavaExec` gradle task such as,

```
task('integrationTest',
     type: JavaExec,
     moreConf...) {
    // Stuff
}
```

you can extends inherit compile- and runtime configurations like so,

```
configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

But, how do you do this with a task defined through Groovy? I.e.

```
def integrationTestTask = project.task(['type': JavaExec], 'integrationTest') {
    stuff
}
```

I am writing a plugin to reduce some repeated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the prerequisite sourceSets `integrationTestCompile` and ìntegrationTestRuntime` will be created and available to set,

```
project.task(['type': JavaExec], 'integrationTest') {
    project.sourceSets {
        integrationTest {
            java {
                // set stuff....
            }
        }
    }

    project.configurations {
        // These two (integrationTestCompile/integrationTestRuntime) get created by the sourceSets block
        integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
        integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
    // stuff
}
```